# Книга по многопоточности

Tags: c#, c++, книги, многопоточность

Подскажите пожалуйста хорошую книгу для изучения многопоточности в С++ или С#.

Comment: Желательно русскоязычных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Joseph Albahari. Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) - здесь изложен материал по многопоточности в среде CLR из его книги C# in a Nutshell (есть частичный перевод на RSDN: [работа с потоками в C#](http://www.rsdn.ru/summary/4512.xml)).

Answer (score 5):

О многопоточности в C# (более корректно, в CLI) можно почитать в книге "CLR via C#" Джефри Рихтера. Одна из лучший книг, посвящённых .NET. Особенно стоит почитать 3-е издание, однако оно не издавалось на русском. В последних главах автор подробно рассказывает об основах потоков, примитивах синхронизации, асинхронных операциях и т.п.

Comment: а ещё описывается как CLR использует многопоточные средства WinAPI

Answer (score 3):

Для С++ рекомендована [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.manning.com/williams/).

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень хорошя книга ["Concurrent Programming on Windows"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032143482X) by Joe Duffy, но она только на английском. Там много буков и очень высокая концентрация мысли.

Для понимания основ очень хорошо подойдет [Windows via C/C++](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4079733/) от Джеффри Рихтера. Там все расписано с точки зрения винды, и вполне доступно.

Потом можно просто взять хорошую книгу по C#/.NET и пройтись по разделу о многопоточности. Подойтут книги Рихтера, де Смета, Албахари.

Answer (score 0):

Применительно именно к .NET, есть хорошие документы от Stephen Toub, например [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957). Посвящен подробному рассмотрению последних тенденций в мире многопоточности .NET (т.е. TPL, async/await). Но на английском.